# NSNumber with locale and exponent

Tags: ios, decimal, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter, exponent

I am trying to program a converter in iOS.

The user enters values into textfields, and the values  are converted.

The results are finally given back to the user.

The output has to be in a locale decimal format, which works.

Also, the output has to be printed in exponent form, which works.

Problem: I need both exponent form and decimal form.

The following code explains what works.

```
//formatting

        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];  
        [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
        [formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

//formattiing

        float myFloat=0.01;
        NSNumber *myNumber =[[NSNumber alloc]initWithFloat:myFloat];
        NSString *myString =[formatter stringFromNumber:myNumber];


        NSLog(@"Locale: %@", formatter.locale.localeIdentifier);
        NSLog(@"myFloat = %g", myFloat);
        NSLog(@"myNumber = %.2e",[myNumber floatValue]);
        NSLog(@"myString = %@", myString);

//output
 Locale: nb_NO
 myFloat = 0.01
 myNumber = 1.00e-02
 myString = 0,01
```

What does NOT work. I need exponent and decimalformatter in one!

I want this output:

```
myString = 1,00e-2
```

Anybody got a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this with your formatter: `NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle`